# Name of a callable that consumes an iterator?

Tags: python, terminology, type-hinting

Is there a common term that might describes the type of an argument-less callable that iterates through (or "consumes") an iterator?

Like the `.readline()` of an io object, or the callable in `iter(callable, sentinel)`, or what the `functools.partial(next, iterator)` function would be.

I'm denoting by a `CursorFunc = Callable[[], Any]` for now, but would like to align my language to one existing, if there's something.

Builtins have `Iterable` and `Iterator` objects all over the place, but find that this `CursorFunc` type shows up a lot as well and would like a (not completely invented) name to describe it.

------------ EDIT (UTC 2021-11-04 19:10) -----------

Additional information to clarify what a "Cursor Function" is, and that it is not a `Generator` (in the python sense).

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import Generator, Iterator, Iterable

iterable = [1, 2, 3]
assert isinstance(iterable, Iterable)

iterator = iter(iterable)
assert isinstance(iterator, Iterator)

cursor_func = partial(next, iterator)
assert not isinstance(cursor_func, Generator)

# A generator is like...

def gen():
    yield from iterable

assert not isinstance(gen, Generator)

g = gen()
assert isinstance(g, Generator) and isinstance(g, Iterable) and isinstance(g, Iterator)
```

Comment: Something that consumes an iterable would be an _iterator_.  Or, using a somewhat less specific term, a _consumer_.

Comment: @JohnGordon I wouldn't use that term, 'consumes', but I can see what you mean by it. In this context, I think they mean it differently

Comment: @JohnGordon, yes, it's an _iterator_ but you iterate through an iterator through `next` or `for ...`. The difference I'm trying to highlight is that the object is a callable (namely `functools.partial(next, iterator)`) that you call to get the next item.

Comment: So basically you're describing a callable like `next()` but with no arguments, right?

Comment: @wjandrea -- precisely put, what you'd get if you did `functools.partial(next, iterator))`.

Comment: I don't think there's any typical term for that in Python. If you look at, say, the [`tokenize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module, `tokenize.tokenize` and `tokenize.generate_tokens` take an argument that behaves like what you're talking about, and they don't use any special term for it. "The tokenize() generator requires one argument, readline, which must be a callable object which provides the same interface as the io.IOBase.readline() method of file objects. Each call to the function should return one line of input as bytes."

Answer (score 0):

Usually these things are called **generators** (*e.g.*, in “random number generator” or [in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)), although in Python that’s of course used to mean [a specific means of *constructing* an iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) (from which one could derive a generator of the other kind).

Comment: I just edited the post to argue, via code assertions, that (for python), generator wouldn't be the right term.

Comment: @thorwhalen: You didn’t actually *say* “What should I call this for `typing` purposes?”, which would probably be too opinion-based; you asked if there were a common term, which this is.

Comment: Generators _produce_ iterables, not _consume_ them.

Comment: @JohnGordon: It’s both: `lambda: next(my_iter)` consumes `my_iter` on the inside but can be seen as a source of values (a “generator” in the non-Python sense) on the outside.